# Backward migration from spring boot to spring core

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, performance, annotations

I know that spring boot is a wrapper for spring framework, so is it possible to achieve better **running time performance** for a application by migrating backwards from spring boot to spring core? If so, what changes need to be made? Is just changing the configuration files and modifying some annotations enough?

Comment: Depends on what your app does and what Spring Boot features you're using. Are you dependent on an embedded servlet container packaged with your Spring Boot app? If so you'll have to consider other deployment options

Comment: Spring Boot is not a _wrapper_ for Spring, it is _a (complex) set of configuration directives_. Essentially all of its overhead is at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot is just a helper to make the configuration and setup of a Spring application a bit easier by using good default behaviours. It adds some functionality for starting the application (configuration), but it doesn't add (that much) behaviour for the "normal" runtime.

So removing Spring Boot will **typically** not give you a significant improvement in runtime performance (in terms of speed).

*If your application use a database, and this is somehow related to your performance issue, then you maybe should optimize this. (Database Index, Better/Less queries, pure SQL instead of JPA, caches, ....)*